# Operating a series-wound motor as a DC-motor

Tags: motor

I have an old angle grinder motor that is interconnected as a series-wound motor with 230V / 1.1kW. I want to try and operate it as a normal DC-motor with its field winding and armature winding separated. Since the type label only describes the series-wound motor data (namely 1-phase AC 230V,) I am unsure how to operate the motor with DC.

Since the armature winding is capable of handling 230V AC it should also be used with 230VDC when operated as a DC-motor, right? What about the field winding? I can't find any general advice online about how much voltage/current such a winding can take and needs in order to be operated normally.

I included pictures of the motor an the type label if that helps. I just want to know if it's possible to operate such a motor as a normal DC motor or not and, if yes, what voltages I need for operation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it's 230 V in series configuration it's unlikely to enjoy 230 V across just one of the windings.